# plot_model function in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the interactions of variables in a non-linear regression function in R.

Here is my code:

```
plot_model(more_varibles, type = "pred", terms = c("accommodates", "room_type")) +
  theme_bw()
```

I receive an error:

> Error in library(plot_model) : there is no package called ‘plot_model’

After receiving the error, I have installed `sjPlot` package, however I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you mean `library(sjPlot)` instead of `library(plot_model)`? I believe `plot_model` is a function in the `sjPlot` package?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to load the package sjPlot. Try `library(sjPlot)` and then run the function. Or you can try `sjPlot::plot_model()` if you don't want load the package separately.